# Json Ignore property only in specific method

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I have a Class So as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "so", schema = "public")
public class So implements java.io.Serializable , IBusiness {

    private int idSo;
    
    private Set<PartOrder> partOrders = new HashSet<PartOrder>();
    
    public So() {
        
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGenerator", sequenceName = "so_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seqGenerator", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id_so", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdSo() {
        return this.idSo;
    }

    public void setIdSo(int idSo) {
        this.idSo = idSo;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "so")
    public Set<PartOrder> getPartOrders() {
        return this.partOrders;
    }

    public void setPartOrders(Set<PartOrder> partOrders) {
        this.partOrders = partOrders;
    }


}
```

I have a method that returns a Json with the SO. But i don not want the partOrders attribute to be included on the response json. I was using @JsonIgnore on the attribute but now, i have another method that receives an SO object and i need to get the partOders.

The question is: Is there any way to specify when to ignore the attribute (in specific method) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Json Filter with a `FilterProvider`

1. you use [`@JsonFilter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFilter.html) annotation to assign a filter name to your POJO.
2. before serialization, you attach an instance of [`SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) to the filter name.  the class has two factory methods for filters that work based on propertry names.

Here is an example of the annotation declaration:

```
@JsonFilter("filter properties by name")
public class So {
    public String alwaysWrite = "alwaysWriteValue";
    public String somtimeIgnore = "somtimeIgnoreValue";
}
```

here is a method that assignes a filter that will ignore `somtimeIgnore` property

```
public void dontWriteSomtimes(So so) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()  
      .addFilter("filter properties by name", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("somtimeIgnore"));  
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);  
    try {
        System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(so));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:
`{"alwaysWrite":"alwaysWriteValue"}`

here is a method that will write everything: just assign a non-existent or empty property:

```
public void writeEveryting(So so) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()  
      .addFilter("filter properties by name", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(""));  
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);  
    try {
        System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(so));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:
`{"alwaysWrite":"alwaysWriteValue","somtimeIgnore":"somtimeIgnoreValue"}`

Answer (score 0):

you put jSON ignore annotation for your class. i think it will overcome your requirement. you can leave unwanted properties here.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class ClassName{

}
```

Comment: kumaresan thanks for your response. Unfortunatly putting @JsonIgnoreProperties isn't a solution for as both methods are on the same class. As i mentioned before i want on method to take into account the attribute and another method to ignore it. Thanks though for your response

Comment: you make second method value as null, then when you need, make it again.please.

Comment: yes the null worked fine. I don't know if it's the most elegant solution but it can solve the fire. Thanks!