# Spring-JPA - How to output limited fields from Self Joined tables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity named employee which has self join with itself. The join is to represent who is the manager for that employee. When I query the records I am getting the whole hierarchy for the employee.

What I wish to achieve is to fetch only few fields of manager and do not wish to fetch an employee's manager's manager.

I tried doing it using `@NamedEntityGraph` but not able to get the expected output. 
Used `Projections` as well.

I also tried the approach as mentioned here

1. [JPA Self Join using JoinTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216321/jpa-self-join-using-jointable)
2. [Self join Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779181/self-join-spring-jpa)

**Note** - I do not wish to use `@Query` annotation

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "employeeId", nullable = false)
    private String employeeId;

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "middleName")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "dateOfJoining", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate dateOfJoining;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "line_manager_id")
    private Employee manager;

}
```

Actual Result -

```
{
   "firstName":"Super",
   "lastName":"Manager",
   "middleName":"",
   "dateOfJoining":"2012-12-31",
   "manager":{
      "firstName":"Super",
      "lastName":"Manager",
      "middleName":"",
      "dateOfJoining":"2012-12-31",
      "manager":{
         "firstName":"Admin",
         "lastName":"User",
         "middleName":"",
         "dateOfJoining":"2012-12-31",
         "manager":{
            "firstName":"Admin",
            "lastName":"User",
            "middleName":"",
            "dateOfJoining":"2012-12-31",
            "manager": null,
            "employeeId":"P67"
         },
         "employeeId":"P68"
      },
      "employeeId":"P69"
   },
   "employeeId":"P70"
}
```

Expected Result

```
{
   "firstName":"Super",
   "lastName":"Manager",
   "middleName":"",
   "dateOfJoining":"2012-12-31",
   "manager":{
      "firstName":"Super",
      "lastName":"Manager",
      "employeeId":"P69"
   },
   "employeeId":"P70"
}
```

Comment: Did you try using @NamedQuery for your Employee class?

Comment: Sorry to say @Abhinav, I am strictly advised not to use ```@Query``` or ```@NamedQuery``` in solving this

Comment: All right! No issues, Did you try using **createQuery** or **createNativeQuery** method of JPA where you pass the _query_  as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using lazy load

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@JsonIgnore` annotation in the fields you do not want to be included.  Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764960/json-ignore-property-only-in-specific-method) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421088/java-object-to-json-ignore-cycle) for more information.

Comment: That will not prevent anything from being fetched; also, how would that lead to having only one level of managers (instead of zero or all of them)?

Comment: That is why I added the two extra links so he could search and find the appropriate configuration to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @ΣωτήρηςΡαφαήλ I did looked into the links you pointed out. ```@JsonIgnore``` completely blankets the line manager. Also ```@JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference``` doesn't solves my case. They will work on two different entities and not on the same entity joined with itself.

Comment: @AashirwadGupta you could create a response object which you will fill it only with the information you want to return.